# Adding a project via references) fails in in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Microsoft Visual Studio:

> Please install NuGet 3.4.0-rtm or higher.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I uninstalled vs and reinstalled. I see there is no nuget package manager is installed. I download and install nuget package manager and it is solved.